# How can I remove u- unicode character from my data frame column which is string consisting of a dict?

Tags: python, pandas, python-unicode

I have a dataframe with columns as shown:

```
   CA   CB      CC
    0   1   2   {u'video3d': {u'data': {u'annotations':[u'....
```

I want to remove u from the column CC. I tried using `apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(x)))`, but it is not working. I read this data from a csv and the type for the column is string.

Comment: How are you reading the `dataframe`? Also, what is the output of `your_dataframe_name.dtypes`

Comment: the `u` is just a prefix to let you know it is a unicode encoded string. it shouldnt be used as part of the actual string, it is just for readability.

Comment: I am reading it via pd.read_csv() .  dtypes is 'object' for all three columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading this from a csv , just do :

```
df['CC'].replace('u','',regex=True)
```

*Since the dtype is **object**, the general string replace method should work.*